# Java: Create a Generic Method out of multiple methods

Tags: java, generics

I came across a piece of code where two methods have very similar functionalities, return the same type, but are different.

```
private Set<String> extractDeviceInfo(List<Device> devices){
        Set<String> sets= new HashSet<>();
        for(Device item:items){
            sets.add(item.getDeviceName());
        }
        return sets;
    }

private Set<String> extractDeviceInfoFromCustomer(List<Customer> customers){
    Set<String> sets= new HashSet<>();
        for (Customer c : customers) {
                sets.add(c.getDeviceName());
            }
        return sets;
}
```

As you can see from the code above, both methods are returning the same Set and retrieving the same data.

I'm trying to attempt to create a generic method out of it and did some research but couldn't find anything that could solve this issue.
If I understand this correctly, using generics, I can define generic parameters in the method and then pass parameters as well as the class type when calling the method. However I am not sure what to do after wards.
For example, the method **getDeviceName()** how can I call it out of a generic class as the compiler doesn't know whether the generic class has that method or not.

I will really appreciate if someone could tell me whether this is possible and how to achieve the desired result.

Thanks

UPDATE: Creating an interface and then having implementation looks like a good solution but I feel like it's overdoing when it comes to refactoring a couple of methods to avoid boiler plate.
I've noticed that Generic classes can be passed as a parameter and the have methods like **getMethod()** etc.
I was wondering if it was possible to create a generic method where you pass the class as well as the method name and then the method resolves that at runtime

eg.

```
private <T> Set<String> genericMethod(Class<T> clazz, String methodName ){
    clazz.resolveMethod(methodName);
}
```

So basically, I could do this when calling the method:

```
genericMethod(Customer.class,"gedDeviceInfo");
```

I believe there's one language where this was achievable but not sure if you can do it in Java, although, a few years back I remember reading about resolving string into java code so they get compiled at runtime.

Comment: To do it Create Abstract class for Customer and Device.
Then create abstract method getDeviceName() .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Device` and `Customer` should implement the same interface where the method `getDeviceName` is defined:

```
interface Marker {
    String getDeviceName();
}
class Device implements Marker { ... }
class Customer implements Marker { ... }
```

I named it `Marker`, but it's up to you to name it reasonably. Then, the method might look like:

```
private Set<String> extractDeviceInfo(List<? extends Marker> markers) {
    return markers.stream().map(Marker::getDeviceName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

It allows the next type variations:

```
extractDeviceInfo(new ArrayList<Device>());
extractDeviceInfo(new ArrayList<Customer>());
extractDeviceInfo(new ArrayList<Marker>());
```

Comment: either they implement the same interface, or they inherits from the same class with that method

Comment: Thank you Andrew, creating the interface is one of the solutions I came across, I must say that you have made it very simple to understand in comparison to what I found online. However, I feel like such approach creates more code than actually reducing it.

Just for the sake of that method,both classes now need to implement an interface as well as having to create an interface.

Do you believe that in a situation like mine where I have only 2 or 3 methods similar to each other,it's better to keep those two methods rather than creating an interface and implementations?

Comment: @Tech, the approach you suggested would be using Reflection API. Such calls are always more expensive than direct calls.

Comment: @Tech if the classes have nothing in common, you can leave them as they are and move on. If they do have some similar methods or there are (or will) places they can be treated equally - marking them by the same interface is a good option.

Comment: Reflection is what I was getting at but didn't know the right term for the solution I was looking for. Considering what I'm trying to achieve and the very little benefits, reflection seems to be a very expensive solution. So is the use of interfaces and implementation as you correctly mentioned. @Andrew your answer is definitely the right path to take should there be more similarities between multiple objects and you've explained it very well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

99% of the time [Andrew answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278503/4391450) is the solution. But, another approach is to define the function in parameter.

This can be useful for some reporting or if you need to be able to extract values from an instance in multiple ways using the same method.

```
public static <T, U>  Set<U> extractInfo(List<T> data, Function<T, U> function){
    return data.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Example :

```
public class Dummy{
    private String a;
    private long b;

    public Dummy(String a, long b){ this.a = a; this.b = b; }

    public String getA(){return a; }
    public long getB(){return b; }
}

List<Dummy> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Dummy("A1", 1));
list.add(new Dummy("A2", 2));
list.add(new Dummy("A3", 3));

Set<String> setA = extractInfo(list, Dummy::getA); // A1, A2, A3
Set<Long> setB = extractInfo(list, Dummy::getB); // 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

using reflection in java will take a performance hit. in your case, it's probably not worth it.

There is nothing wrong with your original code, if there are less than 3 places using it, DO NOT refactor. If there is more than 3 places and expecting more coming, you can refactor using @andrew's method.

you should not refactor code just for the sake of refactoring in my opinion.